# Perfect pairing induces isomorphism of tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, tensor-products, toric-geometry

Let $M, N$ be $R$-modules and $(\cdot, \cdot): M \times N \to R$ be a perfect pairing. Wikipedia sais that this means that the map $\varphi: M \to \text{Hom}_R(N, R), m \mapsto (n \mapsto (m, n))$ is an isomorphism.

**Question 1**: This question is as important as the others, so it would be sufficient for me if you say if it's true or not: Does this definition of "perfect" imply that the other mapping $N \to \text{Hom}_R(M, R), n \mapsto (m \mapsto (m, n))$ is an isomorphism?

Now, let $P$ be another $R$-module.

**Question 2**: Does the perfect pairing in general induce an isomorphism $N \otimes_R P \to \text{Hom}_R(M, P)$?

I wanted to define a possible isomorphism via $n \otimes p \mapsto (m \mapsto (m, n)\cdot p)$ but I have trouble finding an inverse. If this is not true, then perhaps the following weaker statement?

**Question 3**: Assume additionally that $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and that $M$ and $N$ are lattices and $P = \mathbb{C}^*$. Is statement $2$ then true?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your definition of perfect pairing, the answer to your first question is **no**. You are essentially asking if $N \cong\text{Hom}(\text{Hom}(N,R), R))$ and this is not true when $N = \mathbb{Z}/2$, $M = 0$ and $R = \mathbb{Z}$.

The same example with $P = \mathbb{Z}$ tells you that the answer to your second question must also be **no**.

I don't understand how $\mathbb{C}^*$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so your third question doesn't make sense to me. Are you using some sort of exponential map?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^*$ is a multiplicative Group and so a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. If we define perfect so that both mappings are isomorphisms (the one which means that the Pairing is perfect and the one which is given in question 1) then is the answer to question 2 still no?

Comment: $c^0 = 1$ for all $c \in \mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: I suspect that if $M$ and $N$ are free and finitely generated, the result will be true. I don't know how to prove it though.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69418/isomorphism-involving-tensor-products-of-homomorphism-groups?rq=1

Comment: Can you please carry out a bit why this might answer my question?