# A natural homomorphism of dual modules which is not a monomorphism?

Tags: category-theory, modules

I've been mixing up my reading with a little category theory. When thinking about dual modules, this idea popped up.

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are modules over some commutative ring $A$. Suppose $M^\vee$ denotes the dual module of $M$, that is, $M^\vee=\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$.

Is there an example of such $M$ and $N$ so that the natural homomorphism $M^\vee\otimes N\to\text{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is not a monomorphism (not injective)? Thanks.

Comment: Related discussion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69184/a-counterexample-to-the-isomorphism-m-otimes-m-rightarrow-hom-r-m-m

Comment: Dear Buble, Did you try any examples? E.g. with $A = \mathbb Z$ and $M = N$?  Regards,